# How to find previous and next object of an Array for a active object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am not finding any solutions. Everywhere show just first and last element of an array.

Suppose, I have an array

```
[
    { name: "Hero", Id: "hero" },
    { name: "About", Id: "about" },
    { name: "Proccess", Id: "process" },
    { name: "Mission", Id: "mission" },
    { name: "Skill", Id: "skill" },
    { name: "Service", Id: "service" },
    { name: "Work", Id: "work" },
    { name: "Contact", Id: "contact" },
]
```

Here each object has a Id. Suppose active Id is `service`. When I active Id is `service`, then I have to find it previous and next Id (previous `skill`, next `work`). Here I have to find just previous and next Object according to active Id. Here Active Id can changed. When Active Id is changed then I have to find the changes previous and next object id.

I think I can clear the question. For mine it difficult. Please help me.

Comment: When you get a new active ID, find the index in the array corresponding to that ID with `findIndex()`. Then you can get the previous and next ID using `myArray[index-1]` and `myArray[index+1]`

Comment: You probably want [.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex). (If you already have a reference to the object (as well as the array), it's even simpler with [.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf()).)

Comment: at least post some code what you have tried!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [array.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to get the current index, then `-` and `+` that to get the previous and next respectively. You'll also want to account for out of bounds indexes. The function I have returns `undefined` if the index if out of bounds.

```js
const arr = [
    { name: "Hero", Id: "hero" },
    { name: "About", Id: "about" },
    { name: "Proccess", Id: "process" },
    { name: "Mission", Id: "mission" },
    { name: "Skill", Id: "skill" },
    { name: "Service", Id: "service" },
    { name: "Work", Id: "work" },
    { name: "Contact", Id: "contact" },
]

const getPrevAndNext = (activeID) => {
  const index = arr.findIndex((a) => a.Id === activeID)
  if (index === -1) {
    return undefined
  }
  
  const prev = arr[index - 1]
  if (!prev) {
    return undefined
  }
  
  const next = arr[index + 1]
  if (!next) {
    return undefined
  }
  
  return [prev, next]
}

console.log(getPrevAndNext('service'))
```

Comment: good, I was thinking of a similar solution.